# Rails 4 self.primary_key Postgresql bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

It seems that doing:

```
self.primary_key = [:tag_id, :markable_id, :markable_type]
```

on my model, will give me, in update or create, the error:

```
: INSERT INTO "markings" ("markable_id", "markable_type", "tag_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "[:tag_id, :markable_id, :markable_type]"
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 507ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "[:tag_id, :markable_id, :markable_type]" does not exist
LINE 1: ...le_type", "tag_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "[:tag_id,...
```

It seems rails uses the array passed on to self.primary_key as a string on RETURNING. The correct syntax on Pg would be to have the returning columns unquoted.

How can I fix or workaround this?

Ps: this is a join table, I *know* for a fact that join tables need not have primary keys, but rails is complaining on my creation partial that it does not have an id set... Am I trying to fix the wrong problem?

EDIT:

If I remove the self.primary_key statement, I start getting this error whenever my _form partial is rendered.

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey in Products#new
Showing /Users/donato/src/heroku/eVianna/app/views/products/_form.html.erb where line #27 raised:

Unknown primary key for table markings in model Marking.
Extracted source (around line #27):

27:         <%= f.simple_fields_for :markings, :include_id => false do |marking| %>
28:           <%= marking.simple_fields_for :tags, :include_id => false do |tag| %>
29:             <% if marking.object.new_record? %>
30:                 <%= marking.association :tag, :collection => Tag.all(:order => 'name'), :prompt => 'Choose an existing tag' %>
```

Additional info:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify

  has_many :markings, :as => :markable
  has_many :tags, :through => :markings #, :source => :taggable, :source_type => 'Product'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :markings, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Marking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :markable, polymorphic: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tag, :reject_if => :all_blank

  #TODO Correct this:
  #self.primary_key = [:tag_id, :markable_id, :markable_type]
  #TODO get rid of this workaround:
  #self.primary_key = :tag_id
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :markings

  has_many :products, :through => :markings, :source => :markable, :source_type => 'Product'
end
```

Comment: If join tables need not have primary keys, why are you setting three columns as primary key? Rails doesn't go well with composite primary keys

Comment: it sounds like trying to solve the wrong problem indeed. Can we get the error about the 'not having an id set'?

Comment: Edit the question to add the other error. I am using a workaround which is passing one single column into self.primary_key. I know it is wrong, but I know not what to do...

Comment: try to look at this article http://www.bigastronaut.com/blog/2014/riding-rails-with-a-composite-primary-key